# Is it correct to say "and therefore"?

Tags: grammar

In the following paragraph, I have used the term "**and therefore**". A teacher of mine said that native speakers never use this, but I have seen it several times. I am curious to know if it is correct or not.

> I think digital books have great advantages over printed books and
> therefore have rendered them obsolete. For instance, with e-book
> readers we can buy books at lowest prices, while in the past we had to
> take books from libraries and pay a lot if they were overdue.

Also please tell me if overdue is correctly used at the  end of the paragraph.

Comment: Most dictionaries confirm that usage of _therefore_  meaning consequently and it is not marked as BrE or USE. I would suggest your last sentence would be better ending _and would have to pay a lot is they became overdue_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am from the UK. I'm not sure about native speakers in other countries but to me this sounds totally normal and would be how I phrased it.

The second sentence is a bit off:

"at lowest prices" should be "at the lowest (possible) prices" or "at lower prices".
Usually we would use the verb "borrow" to describe getting a book from the library.
"Take" sounds a bit like you are stealing it.

"if they were overdue" sounds like at the time of borrowing the book could be either overdue or not. It would better to say "if they went overdue" or "if they were returned overdue" to specify that the book is overdue at some point after the borrowing of the book.

So the second sentence would become something like:

> "For instance, with e-book readers we can buy books at the lowest
> prices, whereas in the past we had to borrow books from libraries and
> pay a lot if they went overdue."

Answer (score 1):

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20therefore&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Band%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmust%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAnd%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwill%20therefore%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Band%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmust%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAnd%20therefore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwill%20therefore%3B%2Cc0) shows that *therefore* is significantly most often preceded by *and*. It is simply not true that native speakers never use this.